# Using Google analytics for Logged in User to get Session Duration

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have Community running in PHP, I want to use Google Anayltics to determine, which page has most visit by which `username / IP address`.

Is it possible using `Google Analytics` ? Can i configure my google analytics to get session duration for each `username [if available ]` or `IP address` and for each page they visit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA does not expose IP addresses in the interface and  you mustn't send information to Google that identify a user. So while what you want is possible in principle it's not possible/allowed within the regime of the GA terms of service for for those two criteria.

One solution would be to create a hash value from the username and send that along with your hits as a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets). You could then download the page statistics and resolve the hash by comparing it to data stored in your backend.

Comment: fantastic, just one question, can i get the result for each dimension , which will include their time duration for visit on each page ?

Comment: Yes. Query the custom dimension along with the page path (or page title) and the avg. time on page metric (since you have distinct ids for each user the average time on page should match their total time on page, unless my thinking is completly off).